# Is 2 hours enough time to make a connection at Ataturk airport?

Tags: transit, short-connections, turkish-airlines, isl

I have my single flight ticket for Jakarta- Amsterdam. I will arrive in Ataturk, Turkey at 4:55 a.m. and my flight to Amsterdam is at 7:05 a.m. Is that enough time for the connection? I leave on June 28, and arrive in Ataturk on the morning of June 29. This is my first time transferring in Ataturk and travelling by myself.

In the worst case, if I cannot catch my next flight because of delays going through security, will Turkish Airlines get me on the next available flight to Amsterdam?

Answer (score 2):

I've traveled through Ataturk more than a dozen times. I don't see any reason for you to be worried.

It's Turkish' responsibility to get you on the next flight. Even if, for whatever reason, you can't make your connection, Turkish will put you on the next flight.